# Determining the best data structure for a problem form a complexity standpoint

Tags: data-structures

So I have found the following problem proposed a few years ago at a programming Olympiad in Romania:

Say you have a language with exactly N words. Two words are said to be K-similar if they have the same first K letters and the k+1 letter differs.

The similarity degree between T words it's said to be K if any two words are K-similar but not (K+1)-similar.

Given M random words determine the degree of similarity between them.

I was wondering what is the data structure that would be best in terms of complexity for implementing this program.

I have tried implementing it by using arrays of strings or arrays of arrays of chars.

Example: For asdf, asdffff and asdg the similarity degree should be 3.

Comment: Your example contradicts the description. You say, "The similarity degree between T words it's staid to be K if any two words are K-similar but not (K+1)-similar." According to that, the answer to your example should be 4 because "asdf" and "asdffff" have a K-similarity of 4.

Comment: If you look at the definition it said that any two words are k-simmilar and not k+1-simmilar.  Asdf and asdg are 3 simmilar, asdf and asdffff are 4 similar and asdffff and asdg are 3 simmilare. Therefore the set containing thise 3 worda has the simmilarity degree 3.

Comment: Or at least that is the jist of the problem, if it's not obvious from my phrasing I am sorry

Comment: Then what would be the result if the words were "asdf", "asdffff", and "xyzzy"? Would it be 4? Or 0?

Comment: It should be zero

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it sounds like you're looking for the longest common prefix. That doesn't require any special data structure.

Start with the first two words, "asdf" and "adsffff". Compare character-by-character until you find a mismatch. You end up with the common letters "asdf".

Then compare the next word to the result from that comparison. You compare "asdf" with "asdg", and find that there is a mismatch on the 4th character, so your the longest common prefix now is "asd".

You can continue in that way through all the words in your list. And if you run across a word that starts with anything other than 'a', then your longest common prefix is 0, and you can exit.

Based on your question and clarification in the comments, the above will solve the problem. I still think, however, that your understanding of the problem is not correct.

Comment: Based on the examples provided with the problem I think my interpretation is correct. The problem is that the problem was given in the context of data structures. That means that if, for example, you use an array for the words you should implement that array from scratch. Furthermore the structure has to be optimal. This means that if a linked list would suffice(or stack or queue) then you can't use an array(if you do not need the random access that an array provides).

Comment: Also, we have to determine the data structure for each word(again we cannot use strings or arrays of chars if there is another structure that would make comparison easier from a complexity stand point.)